# Redirect not working

Tags: htaccess

I want to redirect the http://xyz.com/freebooks/ to http://xyz.com/shop/?min_price=0&max_price=0

I added this to the .htaccess and it redirects to the shop page but doesn't retain the /freebooks/ or filters like the original url.

**.htaccees**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^freebooks$ index.php?p=5&min_price=0&max_price=0  [NC,L]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Resulting URL: `xyz.com/shop/`

Expected URL: `xyz.com/freeabooks` (with the shop showing only freebooks)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(freebooks)$ $1/index.php?p=5&min_price=0&max_price=0  [NC,L]
```

or just

```
RewriteRule ^freebooks$ freebooks/index.php?p=5&min_price=0&max_price=0  [NC,L]
```

Comment: No change. Both display the shop page (as that is my home page) with no filters.
Resulting page: xyz.com/

Comment: It looks like it is due to the rule order. I installed the rewrite plugin and it is now working but even though the rule says index.php?min_price=0&max_price=0&post_type=product it is ignoring the price filters. Is there anyway to make them stick and show only fREE products?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) with the [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function in your child themes functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_shop_page' );

function redirect_to_shop_page() {

if ( is_page('freebooks') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://xyz.com/shop/?min_price=0&max_price=0', 301 ); 
  exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense but it displays page not found even though i can access the redirect link perfectly fine.